# How to list all services linked to libwrap.a (tcp wrappers)

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, linux-networking

I know most Linux network services are linked to libwarp.a (tcp-wrappers) and this can be check via the *ldd* command. But can't seem to find how to list all the network services being linked to *libwarp.a*.

After some waiting, I created a dump way myself. Run the script below in */usr/sbin*

`find ./ -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec ldd {} \; | egrep "\\./|libwrap" | less`

Found 5 in CentOS7. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, but first you will want to search for binaries linking to `libwrap.so`.

My one liner is (broken into separate lines for readability):

```
for file in /usr/sbin/*
do
    ldd $file 2>/dev/null | grep -q libwrap.so && echo $file
done
```

I've selected all the files I want to look at, here in `/usr/sbin`, but you can look elsewhere if you want.

I suppress error output from `ldd` because it's noisy.

Using `-q` causes `grep` to not output anything (because seeing a bunch of `libwrap.so` would be pointless). And by using `&&` I only run `echo` if `grep` found a match.

So I get:

```
$ for file in /usr/sbin/*; do ldd $file 2>/dev/null | grep -q libwrap.so && echo $file; done
/usr/sbin/auditd
/usr/sbin/exportfs
/usr/sbin/rpcbind
/usr/sbin/rpcinfo
/usr/sbin/rpc.mountd
/usr/sbin/rpc.statd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I learn -q and && today from this. I was thinking that it's normal for one who started to learn tcp-wrapper would be interested in knowing what are linked to it and hence there would be a common & easy method to list it out, no scripting required.   I installed nfs to see do if I got the same result as you. Now I wonder, are the services "pre-linked" or linked during installation of nfs-utils?